# unable to make header of gridview align center due to bootstrap properties are applying

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

i want to align gridview header to center. im using bootstrap theme which is applying to my gridview also [which is set to align = left] . i want to align header to center.even though i applied headerstylehorizontal=center its not applying in gridview.

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

[image]

Comment: id of your gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` with `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center !important"` in you header style.
This will forcefully make it to center irrespective of any style class manipulating this header style in your case it is bootstrap.

Comment: its not html table. its gridview there is no such property in gridview.

Comment: please check now i have edited my answer, this should work

Comment: just add !important in your header style

Comment: getting error - Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign' from its string representation 'Center!important' for the 'HorizontalAlign' property.

Comment: put a space between center and !important

Comment: do one thing add a css class like this

.gridHeader
{
   align: center !important
}

then add this css class in that header tag of grid like this

CssClass="gridHeader"

Answer (score 1):

```
#gridviewQuoteDetails.th { align: center !important}
```

Comment: i have to use in header . my gridview id is = gridviewQuoteDetails,